# CORS issue with asynchronously loaded JavaScript through dynamically created script tags

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

Creating a script dynamically like below will download the JavaScript source asynchronously.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = src_url;
var first_script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
first_script.parentNode.insertBefore(script, first_script);
```

What type of request object is created under the hood ? `XMLHttpRequest` objects are used for asynchronous data exchange with AJAX. Is it the same object used for asynchronous script loading with dynamic script tags? If so, does the CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue applies here too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `XMLHttpRequest` objects are used for asynchronous data exchange with AJAX. Is it the same object used for asynchronous script loading with dynamic script tags?

No, the browser just loads them as it does scripts in general.

> If so, does the CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue applies here too ?

No. CORS applies to XHR calls and cross-origin access, not to loading scripts via script tags. That's why [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) works.

When you load JavaScript into a page, it doesn't matter where you load it from, it runs in the security context of the page that loaded it. So for instance, if you have a page at `http://example.com/foo.html` and it loads a script from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`, that's fine (and it's how CDNs like Google's and Microsoft's and such work, allowing us to load common libraries from there rather than from our own servesr). If the code loaded by that script attempts to do XHR calls, the origin that applies is `http://example.com`, not `http://ajax.googleapis.com`. Similarly, if that script tries to access a window from another origin (perhaps the `http://example.com` page has an `iframe` in it from `http://somewhereelse.com`), again the origin that applies is `http://example.com` and so the cross-origin script access is denied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It makes clear sense. By the way, what type of request actually issued by browser when it downloads scripts in general ? Request is sent to server without page reload and response is received. It resembles similar to the AJAX call. I am interested to know behind the scene mechanism in script loading case.

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud: It's just a standard HTTP request, just like loading an image or a CSS file...